# Looking for the code of some specific font

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to find the command to write the following fonts

[image]

I tried to use detexify but it did not work.

Comment: Detexify does *not* let you look up fonts. Why even try that tool?

Answer (score 2):

The following minimal example produces your output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$Cl(G)$
\end{document}
```

Regular Computer Modern math font.